# Optional dependency in a bitbake recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Assume I have a package `foo` that auto-detects another package `bar` and enables extra functionality if `bar` is present. However `foo` can build and works just fine without `bar`. How can I represent this dependency in the recipe for `foo`? Things I've thought of:

- I could add `bar` to `foo`'s `DEPENDS`, but that means that now `bar` will always get installed whenever an image includes `foo`.
- I could do nothing, but then `foo` will randomly include the extra functionality or not depending on whether `bar` was compiled before or after.
- I could add a `PACKAGECONFIG[bar] = ",,bar"`, but then I must remember to add `bar` to `foo`'s `PACKAGECONFIG` when I add it to the image and to remove it when I want to remove it from the image.

Is there a way to tell bitbake that `foo` builds fine without `bar` but if both are present then `bar` should be built first?

---

To make things clearer, assume I have the following in `foo`'s `configure.ac`:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([BAR], [bar], [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_BAR]), [1], [Is bar available?])])
```

Then in `foo.c`:

```c
#ifdef HAVE_BAR
#include <bar.h>
#endif

/* And later: */
void foo_init (void)
{
#if HAVE_BAR
   bar_init();
   enable_bar_functionnality();
#endif
}
```

So `foo` will detect if `bar` is present and activate or not the corresponding functionality *at compile time*.

Comment: Does foo depends on something from bar when compiling ?

Comment: Yes, `bar` provides a library and if it is available then `foo` enables functionality that calls this library → the library and headers are required at compile-time.

Comment: Can you show me in your recipe how `foo` detects if `bar` is available ?

Comment: The detection is not done in the recipe, it's done by the `configure` script (eg. with `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` or `AC_CHECK_LIB`).

Comment: Are you using a recent version of yocto? Your note "foo will randomly include the extra functionality or not depending on whether bar was compiled before or after" is something that happened all the time back when yocto built to a common sysroot, but now every package has its own sysroot. This has greatly reduced build flakiness. (It also greatly increased the amount of disk used...)

Comment: I'm using yocto 2.2 (customer's choice so I can't upgrade). Separate sysroots would at least make it deterministic but it won't enable the extra features automatically when `bar` is available.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you have `foo` detecting `bar`'s presence at runtime. A more yocto-ish way to do this would be to have the functionality and dependencies clarified at compile time so that when the image is built it contains what is desired.

You could do this either by defining "features" of foo using `PACKAGECONFIG` or by defining multiple packages using `PACKAGES`. The former lets you set compiler arguments; the latter only lets you define subset of files for deployment. Either way, you can define `RDEPENDS` ("runtime depends") that only apply to the foo+bar case.

**Using `PACKAGES`**

`DEPENDS` is a compile-time dependency, i.e. something needed to compile or assemble all of the packages defined in the recipe. These files will only end up in the image if they are defined to be part of a package with FILES.

```
DEPENDS += "bar"
PACKAGES += "foo foo-with-bar"
FILES_foo = "${bindir}/foo"
FILES_foo-with-bar = "${bindir}/foo ${bindir}/bar"
# probably not necessary since bar is included in foo-with-bar
# and RDEPENDS should be set to this automatically
# RDEPENDS_foo-with-bar += "bar"
```

**Using `PACKAGECONFIG`**

I find [PACKAGECONFIG](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.3.1/singleindex.html#term-PACKAGECONFIG) difficult to use, but if you need to compile in bar support, this is the way to go. It takes up to six arguments, including `runtime-deps-for-f1`, which is what you need to get `bar` installed when the bar feature of `foo` is enabled.

```
PACKAGECONFIG[f1] = "\
    --with-f1, \
    --without-f1, \
    build-deps-for-f1, \
    runtime-deps-for-f1, \
    runtime-recommends-for-f1, \
    packageconfig-conflicts-for-f1"
```

One recipe in `poky/meta` that sets runtime deps is `recipes-connectivity/connman/connman.inc`:

```
PACKAGECONFIG[nftables] = " \
  --with-firewall=nftables , \
  , \
  libmnl libnftnl,\
  , \
  kernel-module-nf-tables kernel-module-nft-chain-nat-ipv4 (...) \
"
```

Comment: `PACKAGES` won't work since `foo` generates the same files whether `bar` is present or not (albeit with different contents). And I've already shown how `PACKAGECONFIG` could be used for my use case and why it's not satisfactory.

Comment: I agree that `PACKAGES` won't work, but `PACKAGECONFIG` should.  If the PACKAGECONFIG[bar] feature identifies package `bar` as both a build-dep and a runtime-dep, then `bar` will get built ahead of `foo` (as a build dep) and put in foo's fake sysroot. When foo is compiled it should see bar in the fake sysroot and do whatever it is that foo does when it sees bar. When the image is built, bar will get picked up as a runtime dep. If feature bar is disabled, neither of those things should happen and you get foo without bar. Either way, you shouldn't have to mess around with bar in the image def.

Comment: I didn't say that `PACKAGECONFIG` doesn't work. In fact I did say explicitly that it _does_ work but that it is not satisfactory. The issue with `PACKAGECONFIG` is that now I must enable the `bar` option for all packages that may depend on `bar` which violates the DRY principle.